# SQL Server Alert System: 'Severity Level 014: Insufficient Permissions'

Tags: ssms

I'm getting the following alert when a user launches SSMS and connects to the SQL engine:
Login failed for user 'XXXXX'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'XXXXX'. [CLIENT: XXXXX]

The alert is being generated BEFORE a query window is being opened or a query gets executed. I have confirmed that the "default database" is not set to the specified database where the alert is being generated from. I have verified that under 'User Mapping' the database is not mapped to this user. I understand this is permissions related.

What ideas can you give for how to alter the permissions to prevent this error from generating?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help

Comment: it's a typical SQL Alert:

USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=N'Severity Level 014: Insufficient Permissions – Low', 
  @message_id=0, 
  @severity=14, 
  @enabled=1, 
  @delay_between_responses=60, 
  @include_event_description_in=1, 
  @notification_message=N'Indicates security-related errors, such as permission denied.', 
  @category_name=N'[Uncategorized]', 
  @job_id=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
GO

CREATE LOGIN [Domain\Name] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[DEV], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO